# Visual Studio - missing source file while checking call stack frame

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have triggered a break point somewhere in my code, when I tried to check the function

`vfbasics.dll!AVrfLogInTracker(_AVRF_TRACKER * Tracker, unsigned short EntryType, void * EntryParam1, void * EntryParam2, void * EntryParam3, void * EntryParam4, void * ReturnAddress)`

in the call stack, an open-file dialog popped up and asked me to open `tracker.c`:

[image]

How can I find the missing source files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**vfbasics.dll** should be a dll from microsoft, as you could see here: http://systemexplorer.net/file-database/file/vfbasics-dll

You could see the call stack because you have **vfbasics.pdb** downloaded on your local machine - and that is the purpose of microsoft provide those pdb files: you could see the call stack and that is it, it is not possible that microsoft also publish their source code for you to debug into

Comment: It doesn't matter much if I just can't find source code for `vfbasics.dll`. But I also can't find source for those `libmysql.dll` functions either. How can I find source for `libmysql.dll` ?

Comment: is libmysql.dll your own dll, or belong to mysql?

Comment: It is from `mysql6.0.2`. I'll try to find the source myself, thanks for your help !